# Typeahead autosuggest dropdown is visible even if minlength does not satisfies

Tags: typeahead

I am using typeahead autosuggest for my input filed.
The code is

```js
$(".new-keyword").typeahead({
  source: function (request, response) {
    if ($.trim(request).length > 0) {
      KeywordAutoComp = {
        KeywordInput: encodeURIComponent($.trim(request))
      };

      self.ajaxService({
        url: *****,
        data: JSON.stringify(KeywordAutoComp),
        makeBusy: false,
        global: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          var loc = [];
          $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            loc.push(val);
          });
          response(loc);
        }
      });

    }
  },
  minLength: 3,
  matcher: function (item) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

this is working perfectly fine. But when I delete input very fast, the input length is less than 3, but I am still seeing the autosuggest dropdown. But the service call is not happening which is fine. Why it is happening. Is there any event for minlength does not match?